# How to use corporate proxy in the OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync call?

Tags: azure-active-directory, owin, openid, azure-sdk-.net, self-host-webapi

I am very new to all things Microsoft and Azure and am not even sure that I have selected the correct tags for the question.

In the Azure service source code (that I have inherited from a colleague) the following code fails with "Host not found" because the request is not going through the corporate web proxy (when I run the code at home network, then the call succeeds):

```
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openidConfiguration = 
    OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(metadataEndpoint, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

If I create a WebProxy object by calling:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("10.xxx.xxx.xxx", 8080);
```

then how could I please pass it to the [OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect.openidconnectconfigurationretriever?view=azure-dotnet)?

Should I maybe switch to using another `.GetAsync` method?

```
public static Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> 
    GetAsync(string address, HttpClient httpClient, CancellationToken cancel);
```

Or should I maybe use a `BackchannelHttpHandler` (not sure what it is, comes up during my searches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that by:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080", true);
```

Comment: From reading just this it is not clear what WebRequest is any how I pass it to OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever. Can you please expand the answer with a complete example? Or is this something static that just needs to be called before the GetAsync?